# Query table with german Umlaut in column name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains a column that has a German umlaut in its name. Yes, I know this is an absolutely bad idea, but I did not create the table and can definitely not alter it, so I have to somehow deal with it.

My problem is that my queries don't seem to work when I use this column in the `WHERE` clause.

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5
FROM myTable t;
```

everything works fine.

But when I execute this query:

```
SELECT t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 = '20.02.2014'
```

I simply get an empty result set. No Errors, but just no results.

I also tried:

```
 WHERE t."BADUMLAUTCOLUMNÄ5" = '20.02.2014'
```

But its exactly the same.

And I know that there are entries for the value I use in the where clause, because with the query without where clause that works, I can see that there are some.

Google wasnt really helpful on this Topic, so does anyone know how to solve this issue?

The Column with the Umlaut is of type date, if this is somehow relevant.
And I am on a Oracle 10g database.

Comment: Why do you ever want to run this query ?

Comment: of course i want to run a much more complicated and senseful query, but it produced an emptry result set, and i was able to break it down to this query that also produces no result set

Comment: as mentioned ist of type date, the same query with another column (that does not contain umlauts) produces correct results, I already tried TO_DATE makes no difference

Comment: please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable;` (where myTable is your table...)

Comment: OK, do the values in that column have a time component? Does `WHERE TRUNC(t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5) = TO_DATE('20.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')` find anything? (Just to verify, possibly not the most efficient way to actually query if the column is indexed).

Comment: I don't believe you, that you can run `WHERE t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 ` **and** `WHERE t."BadUmlautColumnÄ5"` without getting a "column does not exist error" for *one* of them.

Comment: @Alexander: Oracle does not have a `show create table`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_Name, belive it or not, i can

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hmm, seems, I've been working with SQLDeveloper too long

Comment: It's virtually impossible because `"BadUmlautColumnÄ5"` is a different column name than `BadUmlautColumnÄ5`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm kind of guessing that isn't the real name (and that your comments are a little tongue-in-cheek); but this is yet another example of where obfuscating data when posting a question just introduces irrelevancies and confusion *8-)

Comment: no, it isnt the real Name, but seriously, I just tired it because of your comment and t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 and t."BadUmlautColumnÄ5" makes no difference...

Comment: @nurgan - it really does - see the [object naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129). Unless the name is not really mixed-case; `BadUmlautColumnÄ5` or `"BADUMLAUTCOLUMNÄ5"` would be OK if it wasn't created as a quoted identifier; if it was quoted (and mixed case) then `BadUmlautColumnÄ5` wouldn't work.

Comment: ok, I now see it, I was already typing in uppercase when doin the query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the column name. it looks like the values in the column have a time component. You can query for the whole day with:

```
WHERE TRUNC(t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5) = TO_DATE('20.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

But if the column is indexed it would be better to do it the other way around:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 >=
    TO_DATE('20.02.2014 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 <=
    TO_DATE('20.02.2014 23:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Assuming it is a `DATE`, not a `TIMESTAMP`. I've specified the display format, which you should always do anyway, to include the time so you can what is actually in there. It looks like your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `'DD.MM.YYYY'` so it will only show the date part by default. Never rely on implicit date conversion, though.

Comment: This works. But its somehow strange, because when i just "select t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 from myTable t", in the result set i can not see any time component... yes, it is DATE. Can you explain this? But in any way, thx

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
SELECT t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 = TO_DATE('20.02.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

If wouldn't work -

```
SELECT t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5 = TO_TIMESTAMP ('20.02.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

You can also try

```
SELECT t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5
FROM myTable t
WHERE to_char(t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5, 'dd.mm.yyyy') = '20.02.2014';
```

Comment: what's the difference of first and second in this context? :)

Comment: no, absolutly the same, produces an empty result set... with both to_date and to_timestamp

Comment: different formats. I don't have access to DB right now, so I can't check if on of these would work on any datatype.

Comment: @nurgan try that then `alter session set  NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "dd.mm.yyyy";` before running your query. It's a workaround, but it is interesting if your query will return anything

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
SELECT t.BadUmlautColumnÄ5
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.BADUMLAUTCOLUMNÄ5 = date '2014-02-20';
```

I think you simply have a problem of implicit data convercions.